# what will be xpath for image in below mention code

Tags: selenium

I am trying to finding xpath for image.below is my code.i am getting error unable to locate the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='./pics/logo  /home.jpg']")).click();
```

Below mention is my table code. from where i am trying to find xpath for image.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;padding-top:10px;padding-right: 3px;">
          <td width="30%" style="vertical-align: top;padding-top:10px;">
            <a title="Access to Data (S,g,...)" target="_top" href="./action/updateTabs?tabSet=requestId=1457516682135">
              <img border="0" src="./pics/logo/home/EMLogoMini.jpg">
            </a>
          </td>
```

Comment: The URL in the HTML code and in the selenium code you've written is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observed that there is a space in your xpath and the URL is different too..

Use below code:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='./pics/logo/home/EMLogoMini.jpg']")).click();
```

Or use cssSelector as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src='./pics/logo/home/EMLogoMini.jpg']")).click();
```

---

```
    List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@src='./pics/logo/home/EMLogoMini.jpg']"));

    for(WebElement e : list){
            e.click();
       }
```

---

How to click by different ways:-

If your problem is that the element is scrolled off the screen (and as a result under something like a header bar), you can try scrolling it back into view like this:

```
private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) {
    int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY();
    js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");");
    element.click();
}
```

if you need you could also add in a static offset (if for example you have a page header that is 200px high and always displayed):

```
    public static final int HEADER_OFFSET = 200;

    private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) {
    int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY() - HEADER-OFFSET;
    js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");");
    element.click();
}
```

If still not work then use JavascriptExecutor

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By."Your Locator"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I tried it is throwing same error. Below is the mentioned error.

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"img[src='./pics/logo/home/EIMLogoMini.jpg']"}
Command duration or timeout: 2.09 seconds

Comment: have you use implicit wait? ... do you have any frame in your DOM? .. is there any other img tag is present in your DOM having the same src value

Comment: use this line of code after driver.get();   -> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: and there is two image for same source. do u have any solution

Comment: Is it `EMLogoMini.jpg` or `EIMLogoMini.jpg`? These locators are extremely sensitive, so you should always copy/paste and never type anything yourself, even for very simple strings.

Comment: you are right.. it's a good catch .... thanks @KImHomann ... Rimhjim I have updated my answer with change .. please check now

Comment: it is EIMLogoMini.jpg i mentioned correct only. still it is not working

Comment: are you able to click now? ... are you getting the same error  ... if you are still getting the same error then there should be frame present on you DOM .. to handle that frame refer :- http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-iframes-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: now i am not getting error. But Click() method is not working.it is not redirecting to other page.:-(

Comment: is it working manually? ... if yes then I have added few ways to click on element in my answer .. have a try

Comment: try -> //a[@title='Access to Engineering Data (Smaragd, EDS/BCS, DIALOG, ZGDOK,...)']

Comment: and this -> //a[@title='Access to Engineering Data (Smaragd, EDS/BCS, DIALOG, ZGDOK,...)']/img

Comment: Hi @ShubhamJain                                                                                                   I analysis and in home page there is a frame inside it 3 more frame.can u help how we can handle it. Below is a code. and frame which i need to handle that is name with "content". inside that we have image and table.

Comment: <frameset id="frameset" cols="*" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" rows="115,*,22">
          <frame src="./head.jsp?frameset=/index.jsp" noresize="" scrolling="no" name="header"></frame>
        <framesrc="/EimWeb/action/loadEIM?portalLanguage=en&corePortalSessionId…lLoginUrl=/portal/action/loginAction&requestId=1457677794455" noresize="" name="content"></frame>
        <frame noresize="" scrolling="no" src="./ticker.jsp" name="info"></frame>
    </frameset>

</html>

Comment: refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170447/selenium-in-c-sharp-how-do-i-navigate-different-frames

Comment: try this first -> driver.switchTo().frame("frameset");

Comment: @ShubhamJain. now it is working fine thanks for the answer. and i am new for selenium could you please guide me any site which is good for selenium beginners

Comment: cool .. it feel good to know that your issue is resolved ,... refer you site :- http://toolsqa.com/   ..............   http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html  ...................

Answer (score 1):

try to remove spaces and be sure that the URL is same...