# Not able to click on button using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click, element

There is a cart link in my application. Below is the code which I get when I do inspect element. I am trying to click this element using id, xpath, linktext , partial link text..still I couldn't get through . Please help

```
<a id="shoppingCartLink" href="/NTNstore/cart" style="text-indent: -9px">CART</a>
```

Comment: Here is the linkl<a id="shoppingCartLink" href="/NTNstore/cart" style="text-indent: -9px">
     CART</a>

Comment: what code you have tried?

Comment: Can you share your code, also check if there is any frame.

Comment: @Kumar What error you are getting? Try waiting for element to be displayed before click.

Comment: There is no frame involved. This is the error I am getting after waited for an element to display...      "Element is not clickable at point (981.5, 32). Other element would receive the click: <div style="display: block; opacity: 0.211702; cursor: auto;" id="cboxOverlay"></div>

Comment: According to error, the element you are trying to click on is not visible. Wait for the element to be displayed and then click. Use explicit wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to click by different ways:-

If your problem is that the element is scrolled off the screen (and as a result under something like a header bar), you can try scrolling it back into view like this:

```
private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) {
    int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY();
    js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");");
    element.click();
}
```

if you need you could also add in a static offset (if for example you have a page header that is 200px high and always displayed):

```
    public static final int HEADER_OFFSET = 200;

    private void scrollToElementAndClick(WebElement element) {
    int yScrollPosition = element.getLocation().getY() - HEADER-OFFSET;
    js.executeScript("window.scroll(0, " + yScrollPosition + ");");
    element.click();
}
```

If still not work then use JavascriptExecutor

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By."Your Locator"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

---

I think there is a issue of frame

You need to switch to frame first. change the syntax too because answer is in C# and probably you need a java code

refer my answer in below:-

[Selenium in C# - How do I navigate different frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170447/selenium-in-c-sharp-how-do-i-navigate-different-frames)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried to capture the frame but that did not work.. Need more advise on this. However, I am able to click on the same link using 'id' in selenium IDE. But my requirement is to automate using webdriver.

Comment: can you post your frame HTML?

Comment: Hi Shubham- There is no frame involved in the script.

Comment: according to the error you have explained above I have updated my answer .. try that .. it will work .. one more thing use implicit wait also if you are not using it

Answer (score 0):

I there is no frame and you tried with all locator strategy then use below java script code and execute using Java scripts executor class

```
document.getElementById("shoppingCartLink").click()
```

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks,
Sadik

Comment: There is no frame involved over there. when I use the above code, I am getting below error.                                                                       Element is not clickable at point (981.5, 32). Other element would receive the click: <div style="display: block; opacity: 0.211702; cursor: auto;" id="cboxOverlay"></div>