# Unable to enter text in the text box in a python selenium script

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to enter a comment in the following text box with details as

```
<input type="text" name="com_data" value="" size="40">
```

I tried the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("Comment:").send_keys("hello")
# driver.find_element_by_name('btnSubmit').click()
# driver.find_element_by_name("com_data").send_keys("hello smirajka")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='com_data']").send_keys("hello")
```

All of the above attempts failed with error message as:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='com_data']"}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.95)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
```

Comment: Is this element is in a frame ?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a frame.

Comment: So your issue is that you need to get in the frame before finding the element. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069737/how-to-identify-and-switch-to-the-frame-in-selenium-webdriver-when-frame-does-no

Answer (score 0):

To handle element inside an `iframe`, try to switch to this `iframe` before sending text:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('iframe_id_or_name')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='com_data']").send_keys("hello")
```

If there is no `id` / `name` set to `iframe`:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver_find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
```

If there are multiple `iframe` elements on page, you can access them by index:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver_find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0])
```

To switch back you might need to use:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```