# Do Frames/iFrames always have ID attribute

Tags: java, html, selenium, iframe

I am trying to automate webpages with selenium(java).

I am working on an automation tool with which an `WebElement` can be spied and saved. These saved webobjects can be used to perform certain actions later.
When spying an `WebElement`, I will get `(x,y)` coordinates with which I execute the following script that returns a `WebElement`:

```
webObject = (WebElement) driver.executeScript(String.format("return document.elementFromPoint(%s, %s);",new Object[] { x, y }), new Object[0]);
```

If `(x,y)` lies on a different frame, this script returns `WebElement` of that `Frame` which can be used for switching the driver. I keep on executing the same script until I get the `WebElement` which is not a `Frame`. While saving this, I save xPath which is relative to the current `Frame` and ID's of the Frames that I have switched so far.

Later, when performing some actions I locate the `WebElement` based on ID's of the `Frames` and xPath.

So is there a convention/standard followed by the developers to always create ID attribute for frame/iframe? If this is not true what other attributes I can rely on?

Comment: An id is optional.  Its unclear what you actually want to do & based on what ...

Answer (score 1):

There is several ways to work with frame/iframe using `Selenium WebDriver`. You can refer to below `stackoverflow` question for more understanding about handling of iframe using `Selenium WebDriver`:

[How to identify and switch to the frame in selenium webdriver when frame does not have id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069737/how-to-identify-and-switch-to-the-frame-in-selenium-webdriver-when-frame-does-no)

Answer (score 1):

As per best practices, each and every frame should have the ID and Name attribute specified. But in real time scenario it is observed sometime the ID/Name of the frame is not directly visible in the current HTML DOM.

### Switching to frames

We can switch over to frames by 3 ways.

### By Frame Name:

Name attribute of iframe through which we can switch to it.

Example:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("name_of_frame");
```

### By Frame ID:

ID attribute of iframe through which we can switch to it.

Example:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("id_of_frame");
```

### By Index:

Suppose if there are 100 frames in page, we can switch to the iframe by using index.

Example:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

### Switching back to the Main Frame:

We can switch back to the main frame by using `defaultContent`.

Example:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I think index depends on how the frames are loaded, so the next time when the same webpage is opened, the index of a certain frame may change. Going by this I cannot save index to switch frames. If suppose a webpage have neither ID nor name attributes, what other attributes can I save or can you suggest how to locate a frame in any scenario.

Comment: IMO, loading of frame depends on the code as it is written so untill & unless the code changes the sequence of the frames will be same. If this Answer caters to your Question can you Accept the Answer as a solution to your Question? Thanks