# cannot click on Agree & Continue button in Paypal CheckOut using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium for my testing a retail website . Once I reached the Checkout page , I am selecting the option as Paypal Where a sandbox url is opening.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-07L974777B231831F#/checkout/login

I am able to enter the username and password , clicked on Login button.

After that I am redirected to "Agree & Continue " Page . Where I could not perform any action.

I could see clearly the button properties as below

[image]

I have tried the below code, but could not perform any action.

```
WebElement AgreeandContinue= driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
AgreeandContinue.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have many input elements in the same page. What about trying to select by class or id?

```
WebElement AgreeandContinue= driver.findElement(By.ByClassName('btn'));
```

or

```
WebElement AgreeandContinue= driver.findElement(By.ByClassName('continueButton'));
```

then using `submit()` instead of `click()` as the element is a 'submit' type`

FYI : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the button has an id defined, so that would be the best locator to use: `driver.findElement(By.id("confirmButtonTop));`

If that doesn't work, then you might have to add some waits for the button to be clickable.

And if that still doesn't work, then it's possible, as it is with many commercial tools, that the button is actually inside a different iframe. Look further up in the html to confirm if this is the case (it'll have a `iframe` tag). If that's the case, then you'll have to first switch to the iframe before clicking the button: `driver.switchTo().frame(...)` . [How to identify and switch to the frame in selenium webdriver when frame does not have id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069737/how-to-identify-and-switch-to-the-frame-in-selenium-webdriver-when-frame-does-no)

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the `HTML` you have provided the `WebElement` with `value` **`Agree & Continue`** is within an **`<input>`** tag. So we have to construct a unique `css` or `xpath` to identify the `WebElement` as follows:

1. **`cssSelector`** :

   ```
   WebElement AgreeandContinue= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#confirmButtonTop"));
   ```

> OR

2. **`xpath`** :

   ```
   WebElement AgreeandContinue= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='confirmButtonTop']"));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try with ID, but if it is not you can try with other locators , I suggest you have to use xpaths:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'confirmButtonTop')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'confirmButtonTop')]")).click();
```

also I will suggest that you can use wait until element to be clickable or visible

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'confirmButtonTop')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'confirmButtonTop')]")).click();
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'confirmButtonTop')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'confirmButtonTop')]")).click();
```