# Protractor: by.model can't find element inside custom directive

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have this AngularJS project where I have a complex HTML layout.

```
<div id="ngView" class="container-fluid">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.test"></input>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

model.test is successfully found by element(by.model('model.test')).

Inside the ng-view, I load different components. One of those components, loads another html directive, this one:

```
<div class="trans-edit" ng-if="$root.editing"> 
    <edit-task task="$root.task " editando="$root.editing " 
     reload="$root.getData" class="trans-edit">
    </edit-task> 
</div>
```

The outcome of which is:

```
<edit-task task="$root.task " editing="$root.editing " reload="$root.getData" class="trans-edit ng-isolate-scope">
<div class="modal-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3 class="modal-title ng-binding">Create task</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" ng-model="task.desTask" class="form-control input-lg ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        </div>
        ... it goes on .... </div>
```

I can't make the `element(by.model('task.desTask'))` work, even after waiting for angular or setting a wait time. Protractor always fails by:

> Failed: No element found using locator: by.model("task.desTask").

I'm a newbie still learning e2e testing, but this is the first test in a
very long testing process that has failed, and I fail to find info on
the matter of directives and protractor.

**I've tried adding an id to an element inside the custom directive, and it can't be found**. Seems like the system is blind to everything under the custom HTML tag `<edit-task></edit-task>`.

Any help would be great, using by.model would be crucial for this project.

Comment: Is the second model actions triggered by the first one?

Comment: Try to check whether this model is displayed. Sometimes model doesn't loaded.

`element(by.model('task.desTask')).isDisplayed().then(function(isPresent){

 if(isPresent){

  element(by.model('task.desTask')).click();

 }
});`

Comment: Check whether there is need to switch the frame before looking for the element.

Comment: Excuse me, can you please carify? I've written some e2e tests for some other projects and I never had to "change" the switch I'm looking in order to find an element. I just had to use a locator.

Comment: Anil Kumar: The element is displayed, I can see it. If I enter your code, it still fails saying it can't locate task.desTask model.

demouser123: if by second model you're referring to task, task is a model inside the directive scope, wich is loaded in the main html:

`<div class="trans-edit" ng-if="$root.editing">
    <edit-task task="$root.task " editando="$root.editing " reload="$root.getData" class="trans-edit"></edit-task>
</div>`

This snippet generates the first snippet I posted.

Comment: I am saying that you may be trying to access the element which is inside the `iframe`.
If the element you are trying to access is inside an iframe then you must definitely switch the frame.

Refer for more :<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069737/how-to-identify-and-switch-to-the-frame-in-selenium-webdriver-when-frame-does-no>

Comment: No sir, I have no iframes going. Unless I am very wrong, for wich I'd apology, an angularjs directive outputting a custom tag doesn't qualify as an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out an angularjs error on the project made the directive not render correctly, thus element(by.model()) wouldn't work. Thanks everyone for the help.