# unable to switch to iframe using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iframe, browser-automation

I am unable to switch into iframe and have a control on it.
Here is the DOM:

```html
<iframe class="ze_area">
#document
<html><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://css.zohostatic.com/ze/v86/css/zeditor.min.css"><style type="text/css">.ze_body{font-family:Verdana,arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;} table{font-size:100%} .MsoNormal{margin: 0px}</style><style>ol.code li { word-wrap: break-word; } ol.code li pre,span,p,div {white-space: normal !important; }</style>
</head>
<body class="ze_body">
</body></html>
<iframe>
```

I am trying this code to run

```
WebElement filebug=driver.findElement(By.id("fileabugnew"));
filebug.click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement filebug_subject=driver.findElement(By.id("fileabug_subject"));
filebug_subject.sendKeys("web erp : test failed to search for web title");
 driver.switchTo().frame(0);
WebElement 
filebug_content=driver.findElement(By.className("//body[@class='ze_body']"));
filebug_content.sendKeys("erp content. the test is failed");
WebElement click_to_assign=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Not 
 Assigned']"));
click_to_assign.click();
 WebElement 
  type_to_assign=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2-drop 
   searchableselect2 select2-with-searchbox select2-drop- 
   active']//input[@class='select2-input']"));
type_to_assign.sendKeys("shashank.choursia");
driver.findElement(By.id("submitbug")).click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the index of the iframe you are trying to switch to. driver.switchTo().frame(0); means you are switching to iframe with index '0'. For more information see [How to identify and switch to the frame in selenium webdriver when frame does not have id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069737/how-to-identify-and-switch-to-the-frame-in-selenium-webdriver-when-frame-does-no)

or

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);   
// your action here
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Please share the error you are getting. Also are there any other iframes in your html code? I have updated my answer with more information

Comment: I can share the url. You can make the most of it.Do one thing.Go to this url https://accounts.zoho.com/signin?servicename=ZohoBugTracker and make an account here.It is free to use.Make a demo project and and then try to submit the issue(file the bug).I hope this would help you out.

Comment: @DieHardCoder, try my second answer, that worked for me. i.e. switching to frame by tagname

Comment: @DieHardCoder, if the solution worked it should be accepted as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I know just trying to execute the code first. @theGuy

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you need to navigate to the parent Frame for that use:

```
driver.switchto().defaultContent();
```

Once you done you could navigate to the frame in which you webelement is based on index.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(i);
```

where 'i' is the index which starts from '0'.

Hope this was helpful and queries do lemme know.