# Python Selenium Clicking a javascript Radio Button

Tags: python, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I am right at the end of my script and this must be the last page I have to go through and I am stuck. I have spend 3hrs with different combination and different methods trying to load the elements.

the page is heavly javascript so when I try and get page source it gives me

> `This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.`

I have identified there are two frames inside the window and tried to apply all the attempts against both frames.

The result when I try and select to the frame

```
**driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="three"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/a/input''').click()**

error

**Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="three"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/a/input"}**
```

i have also tried the below with or without the `[0]` on all frames still the same issue

```
**driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@type="radio" and @value="05"]')[0].click**
```

I have tried this but also get the same error

```
**element = driver.find_element_by_id("reason")**
```

Below is a screenshot of the code in the inspector window.
[screenshot of inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqN6v.png)

Comment: Please show relevant parts of your code within the question and not as screenshot. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info about that

Answer (score 1):

try to switch to the containing frame first:

```
parent_frame=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('your selector')
driver.switch_to.frame(parent_frame)

#select the button after
```

[How to identify and switch to the frame in selenium webdriver when frame does not have id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069737/how-to-identify-and-switch-to-the-frame-in-selenium-webdriver-when-frame-does-no)

Answer (score 0):

Try with driver click on radio button

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id="three"]//input[@name="reason"]")
element.click();
```

or javascript executor

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id="three"]//input[@name="reason"]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```