# Unable to click link in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

**So for a few days i've been trying to make selenium to click `Link1` but without success, i tried many different ways to do it but all of them failed**

**Here is a list of things i tried and what errors i got.**

***Unable to locate element: Link1:*** `find_element_by_link_text('Link1').click()`

***Unable to locate element: //a[contains(@href,'#') and contains(.,'Link1')]:***
`find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#') and contains(.,'Link1')]").click()`

***AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click':*** `find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Link1')]").click()`

**HTML CODE:**

```
<frameset rows="*,1" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" border="0" >
<frame src="/something" name="center" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="">
<iframe id="something"></iframe>

<div id="content-area">
<div id="something">
<div class="Content">
<div class="pageNavigation" id="pageNavigation">

    <ul>
        <li>                                    
            <a href="#" onclick="javascriptcode1">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last">                                   
            <a href="#" onclick="javascriptcode2">Link2</a>                                 
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**My Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def selenium():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://something.com")
    time.sleep(3.5)
    #driver.find_element_by_link_text('Link1').click()
    #driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Link1')]").click()
    #driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Link1')]").click()


selenium()
```

**Edit:** I just noticed that the link is inside an `<frameset>` and another `<frame>`, and after that another `<iframe>` which closes immediately s Also :

`<frameset>` **->** `<frame>` **->** `<iframe></iframe>` **->** `Link1`

Comment: Add a snapshot of the HTML dom. There can be lots of issues. Try ```find_elements_by_partial_link_text``` or may be the element can be inside a ```iframe```

Comment: @afaalgo Edited, It seems like i havent noticed that the link is inside a frameset and a frame, and maybe that affected it?

Comment: I guessed it right then. Try my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name(name)) # use any applicable method
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Link1').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

[driver.switch_to.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181195/5858006)